# Why, when we raise the natural logarithm exponentially

Tags: calculus

If we have $f(x)=\ln(|y(x)|)$, with the range of $y$ being any real number, how come when we raise both sides to the power of $e$ we get $e^{f(x)}=y(x)$

What happens to the absolute value?  Shouldn't we get $e^{f(x)}=|y(x)|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute value Operation $|...|$ can be omitted because the exponential of any real number is positive. $e^x>0$ for a real number $x$.